# If each individual statement in a concurrent program is atomic then is there a critical section?

Tags: critical-section

If each individual statement in a concurrent program is atomic then is there a critical section?

This should be a simple true or false answer but you need to understand concurrency and atomicity.

Comment: „This should be a simple true or false answer but you need to understand concurrency and atomicity.“ Are you asking us or did someone ask you - say for homework? Do you *expect* just a yes/no answer?

Comment: yes basically to understand my assignment i have to first understand this?